# Printer GetObject fails on IIS 7 but not on console (Windows Server 2008 R2)

Tags: iis, printing, vbscript, asp-classic, active-directory

This vbscript snippet works fine in a cmd shell:

```
dim printer
set printer = GetObject("WinNT://Server/PrinterName")
```

If I run this script on a IIS 7 server the following error message appears:
The printer name is invalid.

AppPool User is the same as the cmd user.

Same behavior and error message with the following code:

```
set oMaster = CreateObject("PrintMaster.PrintMaster.1")
set oPrinter = CreateObject("Printer.Printer.1")
oMaster.PrinterGet "\\Server", "PrinterName", oPrinter
```

Edit: This worked perfectly in Windows 2003 but not on IIS 7 on Windows Server 2008 R2

Comment: I ran `dim printer
set printer = GetObject("WinNT://Server/PrinterName")` in cmd and IIS when i really used invalid printer name. I received error message __(null): The group name could not be found.__ in cmd. The same happens with IIS. When I used correct printer name no errors in both cmd and IIS.

Comment: Which version of IIS and what Windows Server Version?

Comment: I used IIS 8.5 on Windows 8.1.